# What technique to use for Hypothesis Testing Difference of Two means - Whole Population and a Cluster inside the Population

Tags: anova, mean, f-test

I have N individuals with M features.
I call the mean of the N individuals on each M feature a "Grand Mean"
For example, on feature F1, I call it "Grand Mean of F1".

Now, If I have K clusters INSIDE the N individuals, I can compute the mean of Feature 1 (F1).

I do not know what statistical test to use to check if "there is a significant difference" among the Grand Mean of F1 and the Mean of F1 of Cluster 1.

What statistical test should I use?

Comment: The question (which isn't quite clear itself) seems to be about clustered sample, not clustering. Then please edit tags.

Comment: @ttnphns done. i think it is quite clear. talking about the mean of the whole population and the mean of one cluster inside the population. do you what to use?

Comment: If your question has been answered to your satisfaction, you can accept an answer by clicking the check mark under the voting arrows.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this exactly. Compare the mean of the "cluster" (statisticians would usually use the word "subsample" or "group" for this sort of thing; "cluster" is used in reference to [clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis)) to the mean of **the rest** of the sample, not the entire sample. Otherwise, you're partly comparing something to itself. You can now use any of the usual hypothesis tests for comparing the means of two independent samples, such as a $t$-test.

Comment: Thank you. But is it possible to use t-test for different sample sizes? For example, if Group 1 has M size and Group 2 has N size? Where it is possible that either M CAN be relatively larger or smaller or equal with N?

Comment: Do you mean I can do this....

Comment: Do you mean I should use the data of each individual in the group on each Feature, for example I will compare if the feature 1 of Group 1 is significantly different from the rest of the group Feature 1? So if Group 1 is sized X and the rest of the group is sized Y where (X+Y =size of original observations), i should have X data for Group 1 and Y data for the rest of the grp?

Comment: "But is it possible to use t-test for different sample sizes?" — Yes. "Do you mean I should use…" — Yes.